how to configure Grafana alertmanager datasource with kube-prometheus-stack helm deployment
I am using the prometheus alertmanager that gets deployed by the kube-prometheus-stack helm deployment. Now I want to connect Grafana and tried to configure a alertmanager datasource what fails with the error message "Health check failed".
I configured the URL as followed:
http://prometheus-alertmanager.default:9093
This URL/Port is reachable inside the kubernetes cluster (curl/wget works from my grafana-pod).
Any ideas on how to configure the alertmanager to be accessible by Grafana?

Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
